# How to capture barcode scanner input when EditText is being focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, barcode

I want to differentiate keyboard input and barcode scanner input. I am able to capture barcode input when it is not focused on `EditText`.

```
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE) {
        // Barcode Scanner event
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
}
```

However, when the focus is on the `EditText`, it only dispatch `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` for pressing the scan button. The text is written to `EditText` directly.

I have tried to extend `EditText` and override `dispatchKeyEvent` on `EditText` instead of `Activity` but it still does not dispatch `KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE`.

Am I missing something? Where is the `KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE` being consumed?